# Ist there a way to pass data from child to parent using Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As an absolute newbie to React, I'd like to pass data from a child to parent component. But if I look for this question, I always find the "old" way using "state" and "callback" functions. See for example this article: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Since all the guides use the traditional way, I'm very confused because they look so different from what I know. For example, instead of using "this.state" in the constructor, I use the useState() Hook.

Is there any way or maybe Hook I don't see that makes it possible to pass data from a child to a parent component?

Comment: You can use the context api - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: It's not possible to pass data from child to parent without using callback functions. You gotta pass a function from parent to child and pass the data using that function.

Comment: Whether you use Hooks or class components, the general React principle of 'one-way data flow' still applies. Passing state back up the tree is possible, but it's swimming against the tide. Almost always its preferable to lift state up to a common parent.

Comment: I don't understand this though. Say you have a dialog form with tabs on it and a save button. That button and handler is in the parent. And each tab is a child component. In this case, when the user saves, I want to have some mechanism for the parent to know if the child data is valid. Otherwise, what good are the children if all they do is display data via props from parent?  I know there's imperativeHandler but it's discouraged. I'd like to know if there's a custom hook way or something to encapsulate logic that a parent can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine that you have a parent component App that has the logic for handling the submit (could be any other kind of logic) of a form that is a child component of App.

The `ChildForm` has a local state to store its `inputValue`.

When you click the submit function, it will call a function `onSubmit` from the parent App and it will pass along its `inputValue` (you can pass any other value that it's present inside the component) to be processed and submitted, in this example.

So the gist of it, is:

- Send a function from the parent to the child as `props`
- The child will call that function sending some data as parameters
- That function will handle the data and can trigger some action from the parent, for example

See snippet below:

```js
function App() {
  
  function onSubmit(formState) {
    console.log('I will submit my ChildForm Input State: ' + formState);
  }
  
  return(
    <ChildForm
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    />
  );
}

function ChildForm(props) {
  const [inputValue,setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  
  function onChange() {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
    <div>I am ChildForm</div>
    <input type='text' value={inputValue} onChange={onChange}/>
    <button onClick={()=>props.onSubmit(inputValue)}>Click to Submit through parent App</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Can we lift inputValue state to App component?

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference in flow between Functional and Class Component. You can update the value of the parent by passing the function with props and using it at the child.

### parent.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Parent = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return (
        <Child updateCounter={setCounter}>

        </Child>
    )

}
```

### child.js

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const {updateCounter} = props;

    return (
        <button onClick={() => updateCounter(some value)}>

        </button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass functions as `props` from the parent component to the child in order to pass data up the tree

```
function Child({ num, onNumClick }) {
  return <span onClick={() => onNumClick(num)}>{num}</span>;
}

function Parent() {
  const [numList] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  const [clickedItem, setClickedItem] = useState(null);

  const onNumClick = num => setClickedItem(num);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {numList.map(n => (
        <Child num={n} onNumClick={onNumClick} />
      ))}
      {clickedItem && <p>You clicked on {clickedItem}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqm6d)